# Detect on template index file if Joomla K2 item or Joomla Article

Tags: joomla3.0, joomla-k2

I am looking for help on how to do a detect if "page" is coming from a K2 item or Joomla article in my index file.

Example:

If "page" is k2 item show this content else if is Joomla article show this content.

The reason I need to do this is I need to have a different grid structure for general pages vs what is k2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Joomla content fully controlled by database. Each page url has atleast one common input: option. Your fact is identify 2 content source: core article(com_content) and k2(com_k2). So just pick the url variable option's value and check.

```
$input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$option = $input->get('option');

if($option == 'com_content') {
    // Show content for Joomla article
} else if($option == 'com_k2') {
    // Show content for k2
}
```

Comment: I'm extremely sorry, I was in a long travel and on mobile device. So I have posted required code only without explanation.